# How to use FindGameObjectsWithTag with transform.position

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello everyone can someone give me a way how my enemy able to chase more than 1 target with a tag("Human") ? It seems that

```
target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Human").GetComponent<Transform>();
```

Transform is not applicable to use this.

Comment: `FindGameObjectsWithTag` returns an Array so you will have many objects.  If you want to chase more than one target you'll have to store the array, loop through it and store each "Humans" Transform.

Comment: @jiveturkey, you should consider adding this comment as an answer instead.

Comment: A valid state machine should only ever have one target, and be able to change its target based on certain conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` function returns an array of GameObject. You would use it like this:

```
GameObject[] target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Human");
```

If you need array of `Transform`, create new array with the size of the GameObject returned by `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` then copy it in a loop. You don't need the `GetComponent` function. The `transform` property should be used here.

```
GameObject[] target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Human");
Transform[] targetTransform = new Transform[target.Length];
//Copy the GameObject transform to the new3 transform array
for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++)
{
    targetTransform[i] = target[i].transform;
}
```

Comment: how am I able to use that to chase the Human ?  transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(target.position, target.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

Answer (score 0):

@Programmer a decent solution but as I have been learning more about the efficiency of ECS and structs a clean solution could be the following.  It will also be more adaptable in the future.

```
[System.Serializeable]
public struct Human {
    Transform transform;
}

GameObject[] targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Human");
List<Human> humans = new List<Human>();
foreach (GameObject target in targets) {
    Human human = new Human();
    human.transform = target.transform;
    humans.add(human);
}
```

It looks slower and it's initial setup may be, but access down the road won't.  You shouldn't deal with straight arrays if you don't need to and now you have an extensible `Human` object.

Comment: `You shouldn't deal with straight arrays` can you expand on this? Why would you wrap the data returned as an array by `FindGameObjectsWithTag` in a struct before using the data? You would also lose all the properties and methods of the `GameObject` class with this approach (except the transform property).

Comment: This is true. You can save off the GameObject in the Human struct and just reference the transform that way.  It may be overkill but I use this to associate things like audio with a person

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my main question was about the reason behind converting the array into a struct. Specifically, your statement of `You shouldn't deal with straight arrays` was interesting to me. Why shouldn't you deal with arrays? I'm not trying to argue, just trying to understand the reasoning for your suggested approach. I'd love to learn something new!